# Applying properties to all level 1 headings

Tags: org-mode

I have a tasks.org file that looks like this:

```
* Monday, January 8 [3/3]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** DONE Have 111th birthday party.
*** DONE Clean dishes.
*** DONE Use ring during speech.
* Tuesday, January 9 [0/2]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** NEXT Leave ring for Frodo.
*** TODO Resist the Ring's power.
* Wednesday, January 10 [0/1]
** TODO Leave Bag-End.
*** DONE Pack for journey.
```

It's tedious to write

```
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
```

each time I want to create a new day, and I need the recursive counting when I collapse the list to view only the level 1 headings (the days).

Is there some sort of snippet I can put in my Org file so that all level 1 headings will have this property automatically added?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to define a snippet that would work automatically for any org level 1 heading. I wrote a function that might work

```
(defun org-heading-w-properties ()
  (interactive)
  (org-insert-heading-after-current)
  (insert (read-string "Heading: "))
  (insert ("\n:PROPERTIES:\n:COOKIE_DATA: recursive\n:END:")
 )
```

So if your curser was positioned on the heading for January 10 and you called this function it would create a new top-level heading, prompt you for a heading title, and then insert the property drawer for you. Caveat: I couldn't figure out how to force the newly inserted heading to be level 1. It will be whatever level of heading the curser is on, so if you ran with the curser on `pack for journey` you'd get a new level 3 heading.